# Distinguishing between save and submit

Tags: infopath, 2007

The requirement is to implement an Infopath 2007 browser-enabled form **without any custom code**. This form is published as template to a sharepoint forms library and the forms themselves are stored in a document library. When the user has submitted the form to the document library, we change a few status values on a sharepoint list and kick-off some emails that need to be sent to specific users letting them know that the form is submitted. We also need to change certain users' permissions from read-write to ready only on this form. You can see that a lot of background processing is done as soon as the form is submitted. However, we do need to provide the users an option to "save" this form as well (which is possible by the standard top toolbar). My question is that how do I check whether the user has just saved the form or actually submitted it.

The option that I tried was to create a hidden boolean field which is by default, false but is set to true on clicking the submit (custom) button and added another action on this button to submit the form to sharepoint library via data connection. This flag can then be pushed onto the sharepoint library to check whether the user clicked on submit or not. However, the problem is that if there are any validation errors on the form, the submit action would not complete but the flag would have been set by then.  Is there any way to check this validation apart from data connections submit option?

I would appreciate if anyone has any other way of tackling this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable Save option from the Form Options dialog, and work with Submit only.

Answer (score 0):

I use a hidden field (i.e. FinalSubmission) and set that to "Y" as the first action on the Form Submit rule. You need to set the form to Perform Custom Action Using Rules in the Submit Options dialog to do this.

Then, until the user submits it, the field will be blank (or whatever the default value you choose)